# Is there a good way to combine array and object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

There is an object and an array.

```
list: [
  {
    oldData: {
      title: 'abc',
      id: 1,
      date: '1982-09-30',
      budget: 250000,
    },
    newData: [
      {
        key: 1,
        data: null,
        value: 5,
      },
      {
        key: 2,
        data: null,
        value: 22,
      },
      ...
    ],
  },
  {
    oldData: {
      title: 'blablablaaaaa',
      id: 2,
      date: '2012-02-23',
      budget: 350000,
    },
    newData: [
      {
        key: 1,
        data: null,
        value: 35,
      },
      {
        key: 2,
        data: null,
        value: 41,
      },
      ...
    ],
  },
  ... some more datas...
]
```

as above, There is more data of the same type.

I need to use `oldData and newData` together, so I want to combine the two.

How can I combine `oldData and newData` so that there are multiple sets of `oldData and newData pairs`?

for example, `[{ combineData: {...} }, { combineData: {...} }, ... }]` here.

I know how to combine array and array, object and object, but I do not know how to do that.

Is there any good solution?

Comment: `const newList = list.map(x=> ({ combineData: {...x.oldData, ...x.newData }));`

Comment: @NinaScholz I'm sorry, I edited question post.

Comment: @connexo Thank you, connexo! your solution is try to map and datas in new Array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired result is unclear, but you did say you wanted old/new pairs. This answer is different than the others in that it produces an array of combined data objects made of old/new pairs, where the `oldData` values are duplicated in order to appear alongside each corresponding `newData` value within its list item.

your original data after the first question update:

```
let list = [
   {
    oldData: { title: 'abc', id: 1, date: '1982-09-30', budget: 250000 },
    newData: [
      { key: 1, data: null, value: 5  },
      { key: 2, data: null, value: 22 },
      //...
    ],
  },
  {
    oldData: { title: 'blablablaaaaa', id: 2, date: '2012-02-23', budget: 350000 },
    newData: [
      { key: 1, data: null, value: 35 },
      { key: 2, data: null, value: 41 },
      //...
    ],
  },
  //... some more datas...
];
```

This code maps each `{old,new[]}` list item into arrays of pairs `[{old,new}, {old,new}, ...]` that are combined in the final `reduce()` call:

```
var combinedDatas = list
    .map(listItem => listItem.newData.map(newItem => ({ 
        oldData: listItem.oldData, 
        newData: newItem 
    })))
    .reduce();

console.log(JSON.stringify(oldNewCombos, null, 4));
```

produces a list of denormalized pairs:

```
[
    { list[0].oldData, list[0].newData[0] }, 
    { list[0].oldData, list[0].newData[1] },
    //...rest of list[0] oldData with newData[n] combos

    { list[1].oldData, list[1].newData[0] }, 
    { list[1].oldData, list[1].newData[1] },
    //...rest of list[1] oldData with newData[n] combos

    { list[2].oldData, list[2].newData[0] }, 
    { list[2].oldData, list[2].newData[1] },
    //...rest of list[2] oldData with newData[n] combos

    //...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` on the array. And use `Object.assign()` and spread operator to combine all the properties of all the elements in `newData` into one object.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    oldData: {
      a:10,
      b:20
    },
    newData: [
      {
        c:30,
        d:40
      },
      {
        e:50,
        f:60
      }
    ],
  }
]
const res = arr.map(x => ({combinedData:{...x.oldData, ...Object.assign({}, ...x.newData)}}))
               
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Why would you use Object.assign and the spread. For spread you can do: `{combinedData:{...x.oldData, ...x.newData}}` or you don't use spread and use Object.assign instead: `{combinedData:Object.assign({},x.oldData, x.newData)}`

Comment: @HMR `x.newData` is not an object its **array** of objects.

Comment: It looks like you're combining oldData and newData properties into single objects with Object.assign using destructured newData to overwrite property values. That's a nice solution if newData is meant to overwrite properties sequentially that way. The question asks for "multiple sets of oldData and newData pairs", though, which I interpreted more literally in my answer. Maybe "pairs" was meant to be figuratively old/new single object combinations like this!

Answer (score 0):

You can map over the array and use object destructuring (`...object`) to create a new, combined object:

```js
const data = [
  {
    oldData: {
      foo: 'lorem',
    },
    newData: {
      bar: 'ipsum',
    },
  },
  {
    oldData: {
      foo: 'dolor',
    },
    newData: {
      bar: 'sit amet',
    },
  },
];

const combined = data.map(record => ({...record.oldData, ...record.newData}));
console.log(combined);
```

This will overwrite duplicate keys however, so something like:

```js
{
  oldData: {
    message: 'a',
  },
  newData: {
    message: 'b',
  },
}
```

will become:

```js
{
  message: 'b',
}
```

Comment: `newData` is not an object its array of objects.